# Trying to re-install VLC player but it aint work

Tags: 14.04, dependencies, vlc

I get this error when i try to install using software center... How do I fix that

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc:

```
 Depends: vlc-nox (= 3.0.0 + ~~ git20150319 r59816 + 33 ~ ubuntu14.04.1) but git20150319 3.0.0 ~~ + ~ + 33 r59816 ubuntu14.04.1 will be installed
 Depends: libavcodec-extra-55 (> = 6: 10 ~ ~~ git20131218.b3189af ubuntu14.04.1) but will not be installed
 Depends: libavutil53 (> = 6: 9.1-1) but will not be installed
 Depends: libegl1-x11 but it is a virtual package
 Depends: libgcc1 (> = 1: 4.1.1) but the 1: 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 will be installed
 Depends: libgles1 but is a virtual package
 Depends: libgles2 but is a virtual package
 Depends: libpulse0 (> = 1: 1.0) but the 1: 4.0-0ubuntu11.1 will be installed
 Depends: libqtcore4 (> = 4: 4.8.0) but the 4: 4.8.5 + dfsg + git192-g085f851-2ubuntu4 will be installed
 Depends: libqtgui4 (> = 4: 4.8.0) but the 4: 4.8.5 + dfsg + git192-g085f851-2ubuntu4 will be installed
 Depends: libstdc ++ 6 (> = 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 will be installed
 Depends: zlib1g (> = 1: 1.2.3.3) but the 1: 1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 will be installed
```

Comment: Try using apptitude. `sudpo apptitude install vlc`

Comment: Tried to install but i dont know how to install something from an specific package...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Command sudo not found, you mean: Command sudo package sudo-ldap '(universe) command sudo sudo package (main)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your repositories first by following command(check if you get any errors while update):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install vlc
```

The -f option will try forcefully install the package.

If nothing works please try removing the dependencies or purging vlc.

Comment: when i do update i get these errors:    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/telepathy/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/telepathy/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found                                                                                                                                            I wasnt able to install. I get the same erro.

Comment: Please remove that ppa link of telepathy from /etc/apt/sources.list. or use GUI from software sources and repeat the command.

Comment: Nothing about telepathy in there.

Comment: Please share sources.list

Comment: http://imgur.com/VcRanSc,pVnsgM3#0

Comment: please share complete sources.list . As I can see there and third party repos which like spotify. check them, is suspicious like telepathy or similar remove them and save the file.

Comment: You should better create a new source.list from here http://repogen.simplylinux.ch or restore default as guided here: http://askubuntu.com/a/192388/172386

Comment: I gave up and reinstall the system...

Comment: That's sad . you should have find the solution